# Not able to see Export option in Power Automate flow

Tags: power-automate-desktop

I have trying to export a Test Flow from Power Automate Desktop. But I cannot see any export option. Do I need to do something else here.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exporting a desktop flow isn’t an option.

This support article gives you your options.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/topic/how-to-share-export-a-desktop-flow-be5ff7c3-049e-4c8d-a201-01a66232de16

These are the options ...

> If you want to share a Desktop flow with another user, then consider the following three (3) options:

> 1. Directly share the Desktop flow through the Power Automate Portal

> 2. Export a Solution that contains the Desktop flow

> 3. Copy the PAD Actions and paste them in a text editor